# Unhandled Exception when using libcurl

Tags: c++, email

I just finished my struggle with libcurl and finally when everything compiled just great I got an error when sending an email. I copied the code from an example and just changed to my server port/login/password.

Here's the error screenshot:

!http://wstaw.org/m/2011/08/22/error.png

And here's the code I'm using: http://pastebin.com/3BTA1fUW

EDIT: CODE + CALLSTACK: http://pastebin.com/DijJnYH0

Comment: What's the complete stacktrace? Your screenshot cuts off most of it.

Comment: Also, can we see where payload_text is defined and allocated?

Comment: stacktrace ? I'm sorry but You have to talk like to and retard to me : /

Comment: The stack trace is the text in the 'call stack' window in your screenshot. You should be able to select all of it and copy+paste into your question body.

Comment: You've cut out a lot of code still. It looks like you might have heap corruption, which means the problem could be anywhere before the point of the crash, including in the code you cut out. Does it still crash if you ONLY call `email()` and do nothing else? If not, your problem is likely in the `MY PROGRAM CODE` section. Make sure you don't use memory after you free it, don't overflow buffers, etc.

Comment: Ok i erased everything except email() and the same error appears. When i comment out email() it works fine : /

Comment: have you fixed your payload_source function?

Comment: but how to fix it ? I didnt make it, I copied it from the libcurl website with examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `payload_source` function is ignoring the `size` and `nmemb` parameters passed in.

curl prepares a small buffer for you to write data into - the size of this buffer is given by `size * nmemb`. You cannot insert any more than `size * nmemb` bytes; you have to wait for the next call. So if your `strlen(data)` turns out something longer than `size * nmemb`, you write too much data and corrupt the heap. This can result in the crash you have shown.

If fixing this does not fix your problem, please provide the rest of your code, and a copy of the stack trace.

Comment: I sent even less than it was in the example (i erased a whole line and put there lik 10 characters) and still same error : / I edited the question so it has the whole code and callstack

Comment: @shym, you must still examine `size * nmemb`, even if your lines are 'small'. curl may pass in buffers as small as one byte if it feels the need.

Comment: but coudl You tell me exacly what I need to do ? Because I'm not that fluent with english and I dont know what it means to examine size * nmemb

Comment: You have to split your strings up, to only give curl how many it expects. That said, check if it's actually exceeding the buffer size curl is asking for; if not, then your problem lies elsewhere (and I'm not sure where)

Comment: ok ill try it. But on the other hand. Coudl You tell me if there is a better way to send email from c++ program than libcurl ?

Comment: I haven't had much occasion for sending email from C++ programs - might want to open another question about that.